# Docker containers in Azure pipelines in privileged mode possible?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

we are starting to use docker containers in our Azure pipelines.

For one scenario we would need to run the docker container in privileged mode and I am wondering whether Azure pipelines supports "privileged" container execution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If docker containers are located in Docker Hub or Local Machine， you could run the docker containers in privileged mode.

You could try to run the following script: `docker run --privileged [image_name]`

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'DockerServiceConnectionName'
    command: 'login'
- script: docker run --privileged [image_name]
```

You could refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59569) about the Azure Container.

> Azure Container Instances does not expose direct access to the underlying infrastructure that hosts container groups. This includes running privileged containers and thus it is not supported currently.

Comment: In our self-hosted agents I could make such a call like mentioned above and I did not get any errors during the execution. Does that mean it works or could it be that I get runtime errors because the privileged mode is not completely enabled?